# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL cache

Tags: iphone, caching, nsdata

NSData +dataWithContentsOfURL has any kind of caching by default?
Has anyone experimented some kind of problems using this method, what is the most efficient way to get Data from the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation doesn't say that it will cache, so I think we should assume that they don't do any caching.

Which kinds of data you want to get

UIImage : yes, I think you should use NSData

Video: you should use MPMoviePlayerController for streaming

Text: I think you can do normal [NSUrlConnection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It also has asynchronous, synchrnous and caching

Comment: I need to get configuration files in XML format, i should use NSUrlConnection, right?

Comment: Yeah, I think you should use NSUrlConnection and do asyncrhonous to prevent blocking UI

Answer (score 8):

Use ASIHTTPRequest. It's a third party HTTP client library that makes network interaction MUCH simpler, and has very nice caching functions.

**UPDATE: Just got a downvote on this answer, which is a good reminder to come back and update. Lot has changed since August '10. Most notably: ASIHTTPRequest is now deprecated, and its author is encouraging people to use something else. AFNetworking seems a popular choice.**

Comment: Replaced my downvote with an upvote. Was nothing personal, obviously, I just didn't want people thinking it was still a good answer. Good work on the update. :)

Comment: @StevenFisher - The number of places in my SO history where I heartily recommend ASIHTTPRequest is staggering. I'm counting on downvotes to help me find them all!

Comment: You may want to consider deleting the answer, at least in this context... I don't think you have to go back through everything.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner - Maybe at some point soon here it will cease being useful to have answers like "ASI really was the way to go, but not anymore". I'm not sure I know exactly when that time will be. I still see a LOT of questions about ASI floating around.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that on iPhone5s the default policy is to cache (unlinke iPhone5 and earlier).

You can handle via the options parameter the cache policy for NSData . For example,if you want to avoid cache, the following snipped can be used :

```
[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

It's best to use NSURLConnection.  The NSURLRequest you give it can be configured to do the caching the way you want but by default it will just do standard caching of HTTP resources that have the appropriate headers in their response.

This is what I do:

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:
                [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                     returningResponse:nil
                                                 error:&error];
```

Make sure to put this in an NSOperationQueue that isn't your main queue or off-load it from the main thread in some other way, though.  Alternatively, use an asynchronous request.

Answer (score -1):

if what you need is just downloading image from a url, don't bother to use any libraries, just a simple dispatch_async call should be OK. like this:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 ), ^(void)
{
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
});
```

Comment: Problem is the image is not cached so this method is network heavy if the same image is reused in many places.